# Thread 1: Signal SIGBART

Tags: ios, objective-c

So I have two views that I am trying to connect with a navigation.

I have embedded them in a navigation controller and created a push segue between them in the storyboard:

[image]

It the viewDidLoad of the first controller I add a button to the navigation together with a method it should call when clicked:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    UIBarButtonItem *myButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh target:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = myButton;
}

- (void)buttonClicked
{
    NSLog(@"hello");
}
```

It compiles fine and I can run it in the simulator but when I click on the button in the navigation bar, instead of logging "hello", I get:

[image]

Any ideas how to solve it? I have run out of ideas. I am using the latest XCode.

Comment: If it sigaborts, then there's most probably an NSException thrown. Show the exception message. Also, this is unrelated to Xcode.

Comment: Try to set an exception break point by going to breakpoints -> click the little plus in the bottom left corner and add 'Exception Breakpoint' and run your application again

Comment: If btype is right, this would have created some console output. Did you look at the console?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to remove the `:` in your target action:

```
UIBarButtonItem *myButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh target:self action:@selector(buttonClicked)];
```

if you want to use the colon define your method like this:

```
- (void)buttonClicked:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"hello");
}
```